# How to remove a module with command line?

Tags: composer

After uninstalling all relevant modules with `drush un` I have tried the following input and got the following output, but I don't think I did it correctly.

```
composer remove vendor/panels
```

> vendor/panels is not required in your composer.json and has not been removed
> ./composer.json has been updated
>
> Running composer update vendor/panels
>
> Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Package "vendor/panels" listed for update is not locked.
>
> Updating dependencies
>
> Nothing to modify in lock file
>
> Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
>
> Nothing to install, update or remove
>
> Package doctrine/reflection is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use roave/better-reflection instead.
>
> Package symfony/debug is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/error-handler instead.
>
> Package webmozart/path-util is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/filesystem instead.
>
> Generating autoload files
> 48 packages you are using are looking for funding.
>
> Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

Comment: You can only remove packages that exist. You probably mean to type `drupal/panels`. 
https://getcomposer.org/doc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `composer.json` for the actual package name.  In this case, for the panels module, it should be `drupal/panels`, so the command is `composer remove drupal/panels`.

Comment: In composer.json for my project I have found, under `"require": {` this: `"drupal/panels": "^4.6",`.

Comment: After running the command you shown I no longer found it !

Comment: I recommend the concise and useful official Composer documentation: https://getcomposer.org/doc/